# How to Convert a ppt file into pdf file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, powerpoint, itext, apache-poi

I want to convert an MS powerpoint (ppt) document to PDF.

I searched some jars like `officetools.jar`, but that requires purchase.

Is there any way I can convert it through `itext` and `apache POI` like we do for doc to PDF?

Answer (score 6):

I am using iText and apache poi:

Following is the list of imports-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

and the method is..

```
    public void convertPPTToPDF(String sourcepath, String destinationPath, String fileType) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcepath);
    double zoom = 2;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.setToScale(zoom, zoom);
    Document pdfDocument = new Document();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(destinationPath));
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    pdfWriter.open();
    pdfDocument.open();
    Dimension pgsize = null;
    Image slideImage = null;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase(".ppt")) {
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);
        pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
        Slide slide[] = ppt.getSlides();
        pdfDocument.setPageSize(new Rectangle((float) pgsize.getWidth(), (float) pgsize.getHeight()));
        pdfWriter.open();
        pdfDocument.open();
        for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
            img = new BufferedImage((int) Math.ceil(pgsize.width * zoom), (int) Math.ceil(pgsize.height * zoom), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
            graphics.setTransform(at);

            graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
            graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
            slide[i].draw(graphics);
            graphics.getPaint();
            slideImage = Image.getInstance(img, null);
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(slideImage, true));
        }
    }
    if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase(".pptx")) {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(inputStream);
        pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
        XSLFSlide slide[] = ppt.getSlides();
        pdfDocument.setPageSize(new Rectangle((float) pgsize.getWidth(), (float) pgsize.getHeight()));
        pdfWriter.open();
        pdfDocument.open();
        for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
            img = new BufferedImage((int) Math.ceil(pgsize.width * zoom), (int) Math.ceil(pgsize.height * zoom), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
            graphics.setTransform(at);

            graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
            graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
            slide[i].draw(graphics);
            graphics.getPaint();
            slideImage = Image.getInstance(img, null);
            table.addCell(new PdfPCell(slideImage, true));
        }
    }
    pdfDocument.add(table);
    pdfDocument.close();
    pdfWriter.close();
    System.out.println("Powerpoint file converted to PDF successfully");
}
```

Comment: Hi ,  can u send me a example of that..I am not able to import awt classes.

Comment: How to download the apache.poi ? can you provide some link?

Comment: Can you please tell me which version you are using of POI.because 
  SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);
can not resolve these classes

Comment: this way is convert each ppt slide to picture, then insert the image to pdf document. not good enough

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using LibreOffice JAVA API to open PPT and to save it to PDF.

Comment: Can you provide some example

Answer (score 1):

Use [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter), but it requires OpenOffice.org.

Comment: i want microsoft office files to pdf so can it be done through openoffice ?

Comment: OpenOffice does not support XML formatted documents(*.docx) but i think Novell distribut this version of OpenOffice that can open and save Microsoft Open-XML formatted documents.

Answer (score -2):

Try using aspose. I personally , haven't used it before .
Here's the [Link](http://www.aspose.com)

Comment: Thanx 4 reply but i dont want software actually, i want to convert it through code

Comment: can u tell me in some detail pls.. i dont want ant convertor rather i want to make a parogram which converts that

Comment: Trying clicking on the link . I provided . Its pretty self explanatory.