# Extracting images from pptx with apache poi discarding charts

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to convert pptx to png or pdf with apache poi but after conversion all charts are discarded. I want all charts also in my converted png or pdf.

version: Apache POI 3.16

```
 public void convertPPTXtoImg() throws IOException, DocumentException, InvalidFormatException {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("vzw.pptx");

    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(OPCPackage.open(inputStream));

    inputStream.close();
    Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
    float scale = 1;
    int width = (int) (pgsize.width * scale);
    int height = (int) (pgsize.height * scale);

    int i = 1;
    int totalSlides = ppt.getSlides().size();

           for (XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {

                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
                graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
                graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width,
                        pgsize.height));
                graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
                graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                graphics.setColor(Color.white);
                graphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                graphics.scale(scale, scale);

                slide.draw(graphics);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("images/"+i+".png");
                javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
                out.close();
                i++;
           }
  }
```

Comment: Why the Excel tag? pptx is PowerPoint as i know

Comment: Rendering charts is not supported yet. See bug entry [#60201](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60201)

Comment: Is there any other way to convert pptx to pdf with all charts?

Comment: You can try Aspose / JOD - see ["How to Convert a ppt file into pdf file in Java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354568)

Comment: @kiwiwings Could you give any example of JOD.

Comment: @Anil I'm not using JOD ... but google is your friend -> https://code.google.com/archive/p/jodconverter/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki